# SharpSvn Local File Rename Commit

Tags: commit, sharpsvn, file-rename

I'm using `SharpSVN` to do an "Commit" after a file rename in my local copy

instead of doing `Svn.Delete(Src) -> Svn.Add(Dst)`.
 
i want to use a different method To keep tracing revision info of my file

The rename function move the info in `Server-Side` ,
from the old target to the new target by using Svn.`RemoteMove()` function.

How can I copy the "svn-infos" in the `Local-Side`?

I've tried to do `cl.Move(src,dst)` on my local file, 
but I am getting message that the source file not found.

Here is my code :

```
private string SvnRepository = "http://svnserver/svn/repo/trunk/";

public void Start() {
    System.IO.File.Move("c:\\LocalSvn\\1.txt", "c:\\LocalSvn\\2.txt");
    SvnRename("c:\\LocalSvn\\1.txt", "c:\\LocalSvn\\2.txt");
}
private Uri RelativePath(string sFullPath) {
    return new Uri(SvnRepository + sFullPath.Replace(Path, "").Replace('\\', '/').Substring(1));
}
public void SvnRename(string sPath, string sOldPath) {
    using (SvnClient cl = new SvnClient()) {
        Uri UriFrom = RelativePath(sOldPath);
        Uri UriTo = RelativePath(sPath);                
        cl.RemoteMove(UriFrom,UriTo
            , new SvnMoveArgs { LogMessage = "Rename From:" + sOldPath + " To:" 
             + sPath });
        //Local
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've just found out that 
cl.Delete() cl.Add() 
keeping the history of the file 
so i dont need the cl.RemoteMove() to help me to keep tracking on the file !

Answer (score 1):

`SvnClient.Move()` should just work for that use-case. Are you sure the exact on-disk casing is used for your invocation of `Move()`.

Subversion is case sensitive. `SvnTools.GetNormalizedFullPath()` and `SvnTools.GetTruePath()` might help when you are not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Beware from using:

```
cl.Delete(file)
cl.Add(file)
```

It may not work just out of the box. If for example a file was renamed from:

```
file = "asdf"
```

to:

```
file = "Asdf"
```

you have to keep the local file:

```
cl.Delete(file, new new SvnDeleteArgs() { KeepLocal = true })
```

otherwise the subsequent add will fail because the local file is no longer available and it can no longer be added.